# What does nonnegative zero-phase response mean?

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, phase, minimum-phase

I am not exactly sure what nonnegative zero-phase response means. If a filter is zero-phase (i.e. symmetric and non-causal), then what does nonnegative imply? And what are the conditions to satisfy it?

Context: This is an error I get in Matlab when trying to design min-phase filters:
Error using firminphase>checknonnegative (line 79)
The filter has to have a nonnegative zero-phase response.

Error in firminphase (line 38)
checknonnegative(b);

Error in firgr>genfilter (line 323)
hRet = firminphase(hRet, s.zero, 'angles');

Comment: please provide a source or reference. The term doesn't make much sense without context

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is actually an error I get in Matlab:

Comment: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Zero_Phase_Filters_Even_Impulse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean here is that the real-valued amplitude function of the linear phase FIR filter that you provide to the function must be non-negative, because it is interpreted as the desired *squared* magnitude of the minimum-phase filter. This amplitude function is referred to as *zero-phase response*, which is the frequency response of the filter when the coefficients are shifted such that they are centered around the origin, i.e., $b[n]=b[-n]$ is satisfied. Note that the filter length must be odd.

If $N$ is the (odd) filter length, the zero-phase response is given by

$$B_{zp}(e^{j\omega})=B(e^{j\omega})e^{j\omega(N-1)/2}$$

where $B(e^{j\omega})$ is the frequency response of the causal filter.

Comment: 1. Since `firminphase` MATLAB function must satisfy none-negative zero-phase. You mean the `firminphase` function can only return minphase portion of just linear phase system? if not explain more please. If yes, why? 2.Exactly what is meaning zero-phase response. I understood that shifting over origine. but that is effects positive or negativeness, doesn't it?!

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd: A zero-phase response is the response of a linear-phase filter with its impulse response shifted such that it is centered at the origin. But you can just use the filter coefficients of a linear phase filter as input to `firminphase`, as long as the corresponding (zero-phase) response is non-negative. See the example [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/firminphase.html#brygv7e-787), where they use a constrained design to avoid negative values of the zero-phase response.